# Remover Aspas Simples Oracle

Tags: oracle

Como posso remover aspas simples de uma string no banco de dados Oracle? Se faço `Replace(teste, ''', '')` não dá certo.

Comment: quando você usa apenas duas aspas, você está dizendo que procura por algo vazio, o correto é usar 4 aspas, assim você irá procurar uma aspas no meio de um texto.

Comment: Exemplo [Onlline](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/15636)

Comment: Era isso, obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem que dar um `escape`:

```
REPLACE (teste, '''', '')
```